# Multiple notifyObservers() on async task not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I using an AsyncTask to get fetch and upload data over the internet. I want to display on an activity the current status of the task. To do that I am using observers, which sends the current status to my activity. So here is a short snippet of my `Background.java` code:

```
private class Syncing extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            sync.init();
            if (Sync.isOnline()) {
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(ObserverStatus.UPLOAD_PENDING);
                sync.upload(); //Upload data
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(ObserverStatus.DOWNLOAD_PENDING);
                sync.download(); //Download Data
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(ObserverStatus.SYNC_COMPLETED);
            } else {
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(ObserverStatus.OFFLINE);
            }
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(ObserverStatus.FINISHED);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
```

This `Syncing` class is embedded in the `Background` class. This code worked without any problem until I used a second `notifyObservers()` call. So in this case, if the user is online and starts the task, the first `notifyObservers()` will be called, but the second, third, ... wouldn't called and it throws the following error:

```
05-10 21:50:21.563 16265-16285/net.myapp.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: net.myapp.example, PID: 16265
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6892)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1083)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5205)
     at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:13656)
     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13620)
     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13604)
     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:531)
     at net.myapp.example.MainActivity.update(MainActivity.java:239)
     at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:161)
     at net.myapp.example.sync.Background$Syncing.doInBackground(Background.java:37)
     at net.myapp.example.sync.Background$Syncing.doInBackground(Background.java:27)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

On the line 238 in my activity, there will be replaced an icon, as you also can see in the error log. But it will occured on line 37. This is where the second `notifyObservers()` will called.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found now one option to fix this. I now using `onProgressUpdate`. So I added the following function:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(ObserverStatus... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(values[0]);
}
```

Now I can send the progress via the `publishProgress()` method. Luckly it works pretty fine.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    sync.init();
    if (Sync.isOnline()) {
        publishProgress(ObserverStatus.UPLOAD_PENDING);
        sync.upload(); //Upload data
        publishProgress(ObserverStatus.DOWNLOAD_PENDING);
        sync.download(); //Download Data
        publishProgress(ObserverStatus.SYNC_COMPLETED);
    } else {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(ObserverStatus.OFFLINE);
    }
    return "Executed";
}
```

Thanks for your answer @jereksel.

Comment: @Yazan thanks for your comment, but I've to wait two days to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Android view related properties can only be changed in UI Thread. `doInBackground` is invoked on background thread that can't do it. To fix this you should wrap `notifyObservers` content in `runOnUiThread` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))) function.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already tried to wrap it in, but unfortunately the async task doesn't support `activity` and with that also not the `runOnUIThread`

Comment: But Syncing seems to be private non-static class. Asynctask in itself doesn't have `runOnUIThread`, but in your case Syncing should have access to parent class.
Anyway, you can also pass Activity in constructor. To prevent memory leaks however consider using `WeakReference`: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html .